# Question about activation function of image task in Deep Learning

Tags: image, image-processing, deep-learning

Let me ask you about the image task of Deep Learning (here, image identification).

DeepLearning recognizes that it can be classified into three layers: input layer, intermediate layer, and output layer.
① Input layer → Intermediate layer
② Intermediate layer → Output layer
I understand that it is normal for ① and ② to use the activation function.

I recognize as follows.
Regarding (1), the ReLU function and sigmoid function are used.
Regarding (2), the softmax function is used.

I would like to know why (1) and (2) each use a specific function by convention.
Also, are there cases where the activation function is used, and are there any results evaluated by various functions?
If anyone knows anything about the above, please let me know.
Also, if you have a reference web page or treatise, please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The choice of activation function in the hidden layer will control how well the network model learns the training dataset. The choice of activation function in the output layer will define the type of predictions the model can make.

An activation function in a neural network defines how the weighted sum of the input is transformed into an output from a node or nodes in a layer of the network. Many activation functions are nonlinear and may be referred to as the “nonlinearity” in the layer or the network design. Nonlinear activation functions are preferred as they allow the nodes to learn more complex structures in the data.

**Hidden Layer**

ReLU (rectified linear units) activation function, is now-a-days the most common function used for hidden layers because it is both simple to implement and effective at overcoming the limitations of other previously popular activation functions, such as Sigmoid and Tanh. Specifically, it is less susceptible to vanishing gradients that prevent deep models from being trained, although it can suffer from other problems like saturated or “dead” units.

A general problem with both the sigmoid and tanh functions is that they saturate. This means that large values snap to 1.0 and small values snap to -1 or 0 for tanh and sigmoid respectively. Further, the functions are only really sensitive to changes around their mid-point of their input, such as 0.5 for sigmoid and 0.0 for tanh.

The limited sensitivity and saturation of the function happen regardless of whether the summed activation from the node provided as input contains useful information or not. Once saturated, it becomes challenging for the learning algorithm to continue to adapt the weights to improve the performance of the model.

Because rectified linear units are nearly linear, they preserve many of the properties that make linear models easy to optimize with gradient-based methods. They also preserve many of the properties that make linear models generalize well.

Because the rectified function is linear for half of the input domain and nonlinear for the other half, it is referred to as a piecewise linear function or a hinge function. However, the function remains very close to linear, in the sense that is a piecewise linear function with two linear pieces.

**Outer Layer**

Common activation functions to consider for use in the output layer are: Linear,  Logistic (Sigmoid) and Softmax.

- The linear activation function is also called “identity” (multiplied by 1.0) or “no activation.” This is because the linear activation function does not change the weighted sum of the input in any way and instead returns the value directly.
- The softmax function outputs a vector of values that sum to 1.0 that can be interpreted as probabilities of class membership. It is related to the argmax function that outputs a 0 for all options and 1 for the chosen option. Softmax is a “softer” version of argmax that allows a probability-like output of a winner-take-all function. As such, the input to the function is a vector of real values and the output is a vector of the same length with values that sum to 1.0 like probabilities.

Choose the activation function for your output layer based on the type of prediction problem that you are solving. Specifically, the type of variable that is being predicted.

For example, you may divide prediction problems into two main groups, predicting a categorical variable (classification) and predicting a numerical variable (regression).

If your problem is a regression problem, you should use a linear activation function.

- Regression: One node, linear activation.

If your problem is a classification problem, then there are three main types of classification problems and each may use a different activation function.

Predicting a probability is not a regression problem; it is classification. In all cases of classification, your model will predict the probability of class membership (e.g. probability that an example belongs to each class) that you can convert to a crisp class label by rounding (for sigmoid) or argmax (for softmax).

If there are two mutually exclusive classes (binary classification), then your output layer will have one node and a sigmoid activation function should be used. If there are more than two mutually exclusive classes (multiclass classification), then your output layer will have one node per class and a softmax activation should be used. If there are two or more mutually inclusive classes (multilabel classification), then your output layer will have one node for each class and a sigmoid activation function is used.

- Binary Classification: One node, sigmoid activation.
- Multi-class Classification: One node per class, softmax activation.
- Multi-label Classification: One node per class, sigmoid activation.

The **softmax function** is used as the activation function in the output layer of neural network models that predict a multinomial probability distribution. That is, softmax is used as the activation function for multi-class classification problems where class membership is required on more than two class labels.

The function can be used as an activation function for a hidden layer in a neural network, although this is less common. It may be used when the model internally needs to choose or weight multiple different inputs at a bottleneck or concatenation layer.

Reference: machinelearningmastery.com

Answer (score 0):

relu and leakyrelu and tanh activation functions in the input and hidden are used for numeric function prediction.  leakyrelu and tanh find signal better for equations and linear trends. I used leakyrelu and tanh for linear problems.  sigmoid activation is used for classification and binary cross entropy problems.  tanh worked well for binary cross entropy problem in credit loan risk.

you can use softmax when your outputting multiple labels as a probability.  In this example, I use the ufo text description to output the probable shape of the ufo.

https://github.com/dnishimoto/python-deep-learning/blob/master/UFO%20.ipynb

['Egg','Cross','Sphere','Triangle','Disk','Oval','Rectangle','Teardrop']

softmax returns a probability for each output label

```
 model=Sequential()
 model.add(Embedding(vocab_size, 8, input_length=max_length))
 model.add(Flatten())
 model.add(Dense(len(LABELS), activation='softmax'))
 model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

egg shaped ufos are the most common sightings